# Why is connection refused on CloudFoundry when trying to rebuild MySQL database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

I was able to create some of my MySQL tables through Spring's jdbc:initialize-database process.  Now, I get a connection-refused response each time I try to run SQL scripts to drop/create the tables.  Also, in STS I don't have an MySQL entry in the Application Services box, but I see an entry in the Instances box with all 0's for id,host,cpu,memory,disk, uptime.  When I try to add a MySQL service I get an error that the "Service name has already been used"... So, I think I've twisted something, and would just like to reset my MySQL database.  The data is inconsequential, and I could easily start over.

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

    Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is a bug with cloudfoundry.com which has hit the services. If a user has created a service called "sample" and user b tries to create a service (could be any service) with the same name "sample", user b will see the "Error 506 Service name already exist" error. The team @ Cloud Foundry know about this and they are working on it.

So for the time being, try to create a service with a different name and you should most likely get that service created.

Comment: Perfect! Gave the service a little more project-specific name instead of 'MySQL', and voila!  Wow...so cool.